# Cannot install Ubuntu 14.04.02

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7, lenovo

I have recently bought a Lenovo Ideapad 100-151BY laptop. Firstly Windows 7 was installed on it. Now whenever I am trying to Install Ubuntu with the Live DVD it is getting shutdown.

After clicking on "Install Ubuntu" and going through few steps I saw one strange thing. The page where it is written Installation Type it is written " Install inside Windows 7" instead of " Install alongside Windows 7". After this when I click install now it says "Please remove any installation media and press Enter". After doing this step nothing happens...

please help me. What should I do.. Is dual boot not possible in my laptop? Is this even possible?

Comment: Why don't you install Ubuntu 14.04.03LTS?

Answer (score 0):

When the dialog appears, select **Manual partitioning**, then if there is free space in your Hard Disk, install Ubuntu there, otherwise choose to resize the windows partition (make sure you have at least 10 GB of free space for Ubuntu). As BeGood commented above, it is better to try a LTS release or install the latest release.

Check [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) for more info.

Comment: I made a free space in windows but when i was trying to use that space it was showing "Unusable"

Comment: Did you make free space during the Ubuntu install?

Comment: Yees I did make a free space.. But during installation it is showing "Unusable"